Symmetrizing of projectors with identical particles
I am dealing with systems of $N$ identical particles in quantum mechanics. The tensor product state space is : $V^{\otimes N}$. (in the question is use the term symmetrized to designate either fermionic or bosonic cases without distinction).
I know that to generate a basis of physical states, one has to "symmetrize" (i.e. either use symmetrizers or antisymmetrizer on the states and renormalize) the tensor product basis.
What i now struggle to find a clear framework for is the use of operators, and the rest of QM's postulates with this context. For example, given that I want to express a symmetrized state in the position basis, i would just:
$\int_\mathbb{R} |x\rangle\langle x|\psi\rangle $
but already i am unsure if this completeness relation hold
Further, I am confused as to whether the collapsed state after a measurement of a set of eigenvalues $\vec{u}$, to me would be:
$prob(\vec{u})^{-1/2}\cdot P_{\vec{u}} |\psi\rangle$
where again the ket is symmetrized. My question is, does the projector $P_{\vec{u}}$ for this measurement have to be symmetrized ($P_{\vec{u}} = S|\vec{u}\rangle\langle\vec{u}|S^{\dagger}$) or not ($P_{\vec{u}} = |\vec{u}\rangle\langle\vec{u}|$)?
Intuitively i would say that yes: because it has to output a symmetrized state, and no: because it projects onto a subspace of $V^{\otimes N}$, of which the symmetrized state is already a part.

The point is that the physical observables, for a system of $N$ identical particles, have to commute with the relevant unitary representation of the permutations of $N$ objects.
This is true also for the spectral projectors of these observables (which are the elementary observables of the system).
The physical meaning of this requirement is that changing the role of the systems in any bservable does not matter just because the systems are indistinguishable.
Therefore, the projectors of admissible observables are automatically symmetrized for instance. This fact permits to restore the standard interpretation of the formalism for bosons, fermions, or parastatistics.

From what i understand the basis of symmetric (respectively antisymmetric) states is constructed by applying the symmetrizer $S=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N!\Pi_k n_k!}}\sum_{\sigma\in S_N} \mathbb{P}_{\sigma}$ (respectively A) to the basis states of the regular tensor product space $V^{\otimes N}$. My question is not so much if the operator is symmetric, but rather can one construct it by symmetrizing the one for the distinguishable particles case.

For instance, given an operator $V(\hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2)=\delta(\hat{x}_1-\hat{x}_2)$, and some symmetrized state $|\psi^S\rangle = S|\phi_1\phi_2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\phi_1\phi_2\rangle+|\phi_2\phi_1\rangle)$. Then how would you go about computing for instance $\langle V(\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2)\rangle$?
I would have done $\iint dx dy \langle\psi^S|xy\rangle\langle xy| V(\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2)|\psi^S\rangle=\iint dx dy \psi^S(x,y)^*\delta(x-y)\psi^S(x,y)$, but here, again, i seem to use an identity $I=\iint dx dy |xy\rangle\langle xy|$, which is not "symmetrized".

thanks for any help btw... I know the questions are a bit rambly, but I can't seem to point out an exact problem, it's all kind of confusing to me.

If $A$ is a selfadjoint  (or not) operator on $H^{N\otimes}$,  $\tau \in P_N$ is the generic permutation of $N$ elements and $U_\tau$ its natural unitary representation on $H$, the operator which should play the role of $A$ for the system of identical particles (on either $(H^{N\otimes})S$ or its antisymmetric version) should be $(N!)^{-1}\sum{\tau\in P_N} U_\tau AU_\tau^\dagger$.
